# Store key and secret in Azure key-vault

Tags: azure-keyvault

We want to store our AWS key and secret on azure key vault because our VM's are on the Azure cloud.

All we want is to keep the AWS secret and key in the Azure key-vault instead of setting them in the environment variable.

Then, we want to access them through the APIs in our code.

I am very new to the azure key vault and wanted to know if it's possible or not? A simple example/reference would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, just store them in the azure keyvault and access them via the VM MSI(VM system-assigned managed identity).

Reference - [Use a Windows VM system-assigned managed identity to access Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad)

Done the Prerequisites and grant the access for the MSI, in the VM, you can get the token and use the token to get the secret.

See the powershell sample below, you can also use other languages, the logic is the same,  it depends on your requirement.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fvault.azure.net' -Method GET -Headers @{Metadata="true"}     
$content = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json     
$KeyVaultToken = $content.access_token     
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://<your-key-vault-URL>/secrets/<secret-name>?api-version=2016-10-01 -Method GET -Headers @{Authorization="Bearer $KeyVaultToken"}).content
```

Response:

```
{"value":"p@ssw0rd!","id":"https://mytestkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/MyTestSecret/7c2204c6093c4d859bc5b9eff8f29050","attributes":{"enabled":true,"created":1505088747,"updated":1505088747,"recoveryLevel":"Purgeable"}}
```

**Update**:

You need to add your VM MSI to the `Access Policies` of the keyvault.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried the steps, but getting the following error:

Invoke-WebRequest : {"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Access denied. Caller was not found on any access
policy.\r\nCaller: appid=123t434t8-b564-8756-9814-87dasvd789d;oid=04bdwj213-3c56-3345-ac21-1vfdsfh7823;numgroups=0;iss=
https://sts.windows.net/a211a444-b560f-112e-5555-4673hjdja/\r\nVault:
key-aws;location=eastus","innererror":{"code":"AccessDenied"}}}
At line:1 char:2

Any help?

Comment: @PKJ You need to add your VM MSI to the `Access policies` of your keyvault with correct permissions, just navigate to the `Access policies` of the keyvault in the portal, search for your VM name(you need to [enable MSI of your VM first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/tutorial-windows-vm-access-nonaad#enable)), add it with correct permissions.

Comment: Thank you! I added myself instead of the VM in the 'Select Principal'.

Comment: Just curious - do you know what Java/Azure API's I can use to get the same you did through Powershell?

Comment: @PKJ Refer to this rest api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206978/discussion-between-pkj-and-joy-wang).

Answer (score 1):

Azure KeyVault has client libraries you can use to interact with KeyVault from your application.

For instance, these are the client libraries to interact with KeyVault Secrets in [.NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets), [Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-secrets), [Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-keyvault-secrets) and [TypeScript](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/keyvault-secrets)

Here is how you can retrieve a secret from KeyVault using .NET:

```
// Environment variable with the Key Vault endpoint.
string keyVaultUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_KEYVAULT_URL");

// create the client to interact with the service
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), new DefaultAzureCredential());

KeyVaultSecret secretWithValue = await client.GetSecretAsync("mySecret");
Console.WriteLine(secretWithValut.Value);
```

For more details, check out the [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets/samples/Sample3_GetSecrets.md#listing-secrets) page on the .NET repo.